# Can I leave a cake / cupcakes frosted with cream cheese frosting out on the counter?

Tags: baking, food-safety, storage-method, storage-lifetime, cake

I need to frost a cake and cupcakes with a cream cheese frosting for a late morning party tomorrow. I do not do a lot of baking so I'm concerned about when I should frost the cakes. For the sake of time tomorrow I'd prefer to frost the cakes this evening, but am worried about overnight storage of a cream cheese frosting.

- Can I frost the cakes tonight and leave them frosted on the counter?
- If left on the counter do they need to be covered?
- Would it be better to place the cakes in the refrigerator?
- Is my best bet to wait until tomorrow before frosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the dairy products, you shouldn't leave it un-chilled for more than 4 hours.

It's always best to cover your food to prevent dust (or cat fur, for example) from covering it.

Unless the frosting is really wet and gooey (which might run into the cake), it's OK to frost now.

Comment: What is it about gooey frosting which would warrant holding off?

Comment: @ahsteele - Added more above, thanks.  For a really wet frosting, I'd be concerned about it running inti the cake given too much time.