# How long can frosting with butter, powdered sugar, salt, vanilla, and milk, that is covered with fondant be left out of the refrigerator?

Tags: baking, food-safety, cake, refrigerator, frosting

I'm making a 9x13 chocolate cake, frosted with a vanilla buttercream, (not filled) and covered with black Fondarific fondant.

Here's the ingredients for the frosting:

- 1/2 cup unsalted butter
- 1-2 cups confectioners sugar
- 1/8 teaspoon salt
- 1/2 tablespoon vanilla
- up to 2 tablespoons milk

The cake is going to be finished tonight, and eaten tomorrow afternoon. Is it safe to leave it out of the fridge?

Comment: Here are a couple of similar questions: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25168/can-i-leave-a-cake-cupcakes-frosted-with-cream-cheese-frosting-out-on-the-coun and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/what-kind-of-frosting-doesnt-need-to-be-refrigerated.

Answer (score 4):

I've made many a cream cheese quick frosting and have never needed to refrigerate one.

The Joy of Cooking says a quick icing made with powdered sugar, butter and a bit of dairy will keep at room temperature for up to 3 days.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the dairy in your frosting, it really ought to be chilled overnight.  It could warm up on to room temperature for a few hours.

Also, do cover the cake, so dust and stuff doesn't get on it.

Comment: I've made a few cakes before, but this is my first time using fondant. I've heard that if you refrigerate fondant it will be "ruined"? This is my main concern. Thank you for the input!!

Comment: Also depends a lot on the temperature. Although I make vegan buttercream (using margarine and soymilk), it does have a tendency to get rather runny if it's hot and humid.

Answer (score 0):

The sugar in the icing pulls water molecules close to it, so it is less available to any life, and some of it will evaporate too. So it probably wouldn't need much or any refrigeration.